A film about a young girl who takes revenge after her friends read her journal
The film came out in late 90s or early 00s. A girl and her friends are out playing until another girl finds the journal of the main character and reads it to the rest. There is trouble at home regarding the babysitter and the young girl is taken to counseling. She seeks out revenge on her friends as they gang up on her.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

This sounds like Harriet the Spy which came out in 1996. Harriet spies on her friends and writes down observations about them in her journal. She tells herself she is being honest and writes down what she sees as the truth, which isn't always kind. When her friends find her journal and read what she has written about them, they are offended and start a Spy Catchers Club against her. The babysitter is called Golly and has looked after Harriet since she was a baby, but resigns.

Yes, It is Harriet the Spy.
